# Google API client breaks name resolution for paho MQTT in a docker context

Tags: python, docker, google-api, mqtt, paho

My (home grade) code accesses the Google Calendar API and then publishes information it finds there to a MQTT bus (<del>the last part may not be relevant</del> it actually is).

It used to run as a service on my server and I decided to move it into a docker container (also on my server, I run many of them - both foreign ones from Docker Hob and my own).

**The problem I encounter is that calling the Google API libraries apparently breaks name resolution in paho MQTT when ran in a docker container.**

The following code works OK when started from the command line of my server (keys and endpoints redacted)

```
import googleapiclient.discovery
import paho.mqtt.publish
from google.oauth2 import service_account as google_oauth2_service_account

paho.mqtt.publish.single(
    topic=f"testtopic",
    payload="before google",
    retain=True,
    hostname='mqtt.mydomain'
)
print("before google")

google_credentials = google_oauth2_service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(
    {
        "type": "service_account",
        "project_id": "myprojectid",
        "private_key_id": "8...4",
        "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nM....Kag==\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
        "client_email": "smthg@smthg.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
        "client_id": "1...9",
        "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
        "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
        "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
        "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/XXX%40dXXX.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
    },
    scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'],
    subject='XXX@YYYY'
)
google_service = googleapiclient.discovery.build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=google_credentials, cache_discovery=False)
print("after google")

paho.mqtt.publish.single(
    topic=f"testtopic",
    payload="after google",
    retain=True,
    hostname='mqtt.mydomain'
)
print("before end of script")
```

In an MQTT explorer I see that the topic has been published to twice, with `before google` and `after google`, and the output is

```
before google
after google
end of script
```

So far, so good.

I then moved that code file into docker via the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN apt update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt install -y python3-arrow python3-pip python3-paho-mqtt
RUN pip3 install google-api-python-client oauth2client
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
CMD python3 googlecalendartest.py ; sleep 1000
```

The build went fine but the program crashes with (this is the only log)

```
before google
after google
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "googlecalendartest.py", line 32, in <module>
    paho.mqtt.publish.single(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/publish.py", line 227, in single
    multiple([msg], hostname, port, client_id, keepalive, will, auth, tls,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/publish.py", line 163, in multiple
    client.connect(hostname, port, keepalive)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 937, in connect
    return self.reconnect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 1071, in reconnect
    sock = self._create_socket_connection()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 3522, in _create_socket_connection
    return socket.create_connection(addr, source_address=source, timeout=self._keepalive)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 787, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 918, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

I **do see** that `testtopic` received a payload of `before google`, but the one after the Google API calls is not there anymore.

`socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known` suggests that `mqtt.mydomain` is not resolvable (I think).

**EDIT**: I added a `print(requests.get("http://google.com").status_code)` call after the Google API part and it works, so resolution is fine.

It means that the resolution is broken only for paho MQTT, I will probably open a Issue in their repo.

Comment: Just checking, the exact same test case runs fine outside Docker e.g. on the host os of the same machine?

Comment: @hardillb: I develop on Windows 10 - it works. I then run the docker on Docker for Desktop, using WSL2 - this is where it does not work (this uses the docker engine of WSL2). Running directly in WSL2 works. So this is really something with paho + API Google + docker.